# is it possible to preserve and continue to work with an image on rotation?

Tags: javascript, signaturepad

using [Signature-Pad](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad/) and as it's being used to enter a quick sketch rather than a signature, want to be able to allow the user to rotate the phone/ipad and continue to draw.

using the example:

```
function resizeCanvas() {
    dta = signaturePad.toData();
    var ratio =  Math.max(window.devicePixelRatio || 1, 1);
 
    // This part causes the canvas to be cleared
    canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * ratio;
    canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * ratio;
    canvas.getContext("2d").scale(ratio, ratio);

    signaturePad.fromData(dta);
}
```

but while this preserves the image, when I attempt to draw on it after rotation the offset/scale is wrong.

if I change the last line to `signaturePad.clear();` to reset, then positioning and scale is right for the new drawing.

I also tried setting the `{ratio, width, height, xOffset, yOffset}` when doing a `fromDataURL` on the stored image and get the same problem